# Array Angular - IONIC

Tags: array, ionic

soy principiante esto y estoy intentado que al pulsar un botón me devuelva los registros de base de datos (firebase) la cuestion es que la primera vez que pulso el botón me dice que :

```
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: miarray is not iterable
TypeError: miarray is not iterable
```

En el HTML tengo el botón que llama a esta función :

```
  async prueba(email, password){
 const loading = await this.LoadingController.create({
    message: 'Loading.....'
});
await loading.present();
this.userService.getTodos().subscribe( res => {loading.dismiss(); this.pruebas = res;});
  let  miarray = this.pruebas;
  if (miarray) 
  console.log(miarray);
  for (let prueba of miarray){
    console.log(prueba);
    }
  }
```

Lo que pasa es que la segunda,tercera,... vez que pulso el botón si me devuelve bien el array, que debería hacer? Deberia iniciarlo en el ngOnInit ?  A continuacion os indico como he creado los arrays de pruebas y miarray que son de tipo UsersI, una interface.

```
pruebas: UsersI[];
miarray: UsersI[];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pon la inicialización de `miarray` dentro del bloque del subscribe:

```
this.userService.getTodos().subscribe( res => {
       loading.dismiss(); 
       this.pruebas = res;
        let  miarray = this.pruebas;
        if (miarray) 
          console.log(miarray);
        for (let prueba of miarray){
          console.log(prueba);
        }
      }
    });
```